# After transforming an element out of the page using CSS3, text behaves still as if it was there

Tags: jquery, html, css, less, transform

I am trying to toggle a submenu to slide out of view in order to give more space for reading the main content of an html5 web-page. The animation is done by using the css3 `transform: translateX();` property, which is toggled by adding a class to the submenu element using jquery.
Additionally, I would like to make this submenu sticky as soon as the user scrolled past the header, which already works. When the submenu is `position: fixed`, the site behaves like intended. If it is not, the text of the `main > article` elements does not extend past the areas that were previously occupied be the submenu, although the `article` element itself does (see the the bottom border of the titles). This picture illustrates my problem:

[image: Unoccupied space]

```js
$( "#hideButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#subnav" ).toggleClass( "hideSubnav" );
  $( "main" ).toggleClass( "hideSubnav" );
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  margin-left: 275px;
  transition: margin 1s;
}
main.hideSubnav {
  transition: margin 1s;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
main h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
}
#subnav {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  transition: transform 1s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#subnav.hideSubnav {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
}
#subnav.fixnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<i id="hideButton">&lt;</i>
<aside id="subnav">
  <nav>
    <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
    <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
    <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
    <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
    <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
  </nav>
</aside>
<main>
  <article>
    <h1>Funny Text</h1>
    Some funny text that is here.
  </article>
</main>
</body>
```

`aside` may be either positioned as `static` or `fixed`, depending on how far the user scrolled in the page.

I added the `fixnav` class to the `#subnav` id. It will be added to the subnav as soon as the user scrolls past the header. The according jQuery looks like:

```
$( window ).on("scroll", function() {
  var fromTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
  $( "#subnav" ).toggleClass( "fixnav", (fromTop > headerHeight ));
});
```

`headerHeight` will be set at the beginning of the script, it will get the outer Height of the header.

The stylesheet is written in LESS, you may check the `main.less` file in order to get an better overview of the whole stylesheet.
The problem occurs with Firefox (50.1) as well as Chrome (55.0). IE / Edge have not been tested yet, as I do not have direct access to it.
Any ideas to fix my mistake are appreciated!

Comment: Transforms happen after all layout, and are purely visual. Also, please use the snippet tool instead of linking to an external page (future visitors will never see the original problem after you fix it).

Comment: add your JS for scroll you used

Comment: Thanks @Kroltan , I added an jsfiddle Example for my problem.

Comment: I added the snippet @Raviteja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the problem is, `transform` is not a layout-aware property (just made up that term, so don't try googling it). It is applied after all layouting is done, even after rendering (thats why stuff gets blurry if you overscale with `transform`). So it cannot affect layout of other elements.

---

## Flexbox

If you can tolerate [`display: flex`'s compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (e.g. no IE), you can use that to *greatly* simplify the margin juggling and `transform`. More information [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```js
$( "#hideButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#subnav" ).toggleClass( "hideSubnav" );
  $( "main" ).toggleClass( "hideSubnav" );
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex; /* container uses flex for laying out its children */
}
main {
  flex: 1; /* set the basis weight to 1, and since the other elements are 0 (default), it fills the remaining space */
}
main h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
}
#hideButton {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#subnav {
  width: 250px;
  order: -1; /* stick it to the leftmost portion of the screen, regardless of its appearance order on the HTML */
  transition: margin 1s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#subnav.hideSubnav {
  margin-left: -250px; /*push the element the same amount than of its width to the left */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <i id="hideButton">&lt;</i>
  <aside id="subnav">
    <nav>
      <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
      <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
      <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
      <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
      <a href="#SomeSection">Some Section</a>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <article>
      <h1>Funny Text</h1>
      Some funny text that is here.
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Now thats what I consider to be helpful, thank you a lot!

Comment: @pole_mp Thanks! Do take note that Flex does not work at all on old IEs, and very weirdly on current ones. But if your target audience doesn't use IE, `flex` is the best thing since sliced bread.

Comment: this will be indeed a little problem for me. Still, I do believe that if someone neglects up-to-date browsing, she / he has a bad time on the web